# AOP problem running Spring unit tests

Tags: java, spring, transactions, junit, aop

I have a Spring web application which is configured to use JDK proxying for AOP. The AOP annotations (such as @Transactional) are declared on the interfaces, rather than the implementation classes.

The application itself works fine, but when I run the unit tests, it seems to be attempting to use CGLIB for the AOP functionality (instead of JDK proxying). This causes the tests to fail - I've appended the stack trace below.

I don't understand why CGLIB is being used when I run the tests, because the Spring configuration is largely the same as when the application is running. One possibly significant difference is that the test configuration uses a [DataSourceTransactionManager](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.0/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceTransactionManager.html) instead of a JTA transaction manager. The test classes themselves all extend [AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests.html), could it be that this class is somehow hard-wired to use CGLIB?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class $Proxy25]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class $Proxy25
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:488)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:363)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:361)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class $Proxy25
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:446)
    at net.sf.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:201)
    ... 86 more
```

**EDIT: One of the commentators requested that I post the Spring configuration**. I've included it below in abbreviated form (i.e. irrelevant beans and XML namespaces omitted).

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>                 
    <!-- ANNOTATION SUPPORT -->
    <!-- Include basic annotation support -->
    <context:annotation-config/>        

    <!-- CONTROLLERS -->
    <!-- Controllers, force scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.onebigplanet.web.controller,com.onebigplanet.web.ws.*"/>  

    <!-- Post-processor for @Aspect annotated beans, which converts them into AOP advice -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator">
        <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- An @Aspect bean that converts exceptions thrown in POJO service implementation classes to runtime exceptions  -->
    <bean id="permissionAdvisor" class="com.onebigplanet.web.advisor.PermissionAdvisor"/>
    <bean id="businessIntelligenceAdvisor" class="com.onebigplanet.web.advisor.bi.BusinessIntelligenceAdvisor"/>        

    <!-- Finds the controllers and sets an interceptor on each one -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <bean class="com.onebigplanet.web.interceptor.PortalInterceptor"/>              
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean> 

    <!-- METHOD HANDLER ADAPTER --> 
    <!-- Finds mapping of url through annotation on methods of Controller -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
        <property name="webBindingInitializer">
            <bean class="com.onebigplanet.web.binder.WebBindingInitializer"/>
        </property>
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

**applicationContext-service.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans> 
    <!-- Declares a bunch of bean post-processors -->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.onebigplanet.service.impl,com.onebigplanet.dao.impl.mysql" annotation-config="false"/>    

    <!-- Property configurer -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/obp-service.properties" />
    </bean> 

    <!-- Post-processor for @Aspect annotated beans, which converts them into AOP advice -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator"/>

    <!-- An @Aspect bean that converts exceptions thrown in service implementation classes to runtime exceptions  -->
    <bean id="exceptionAdvisor" class="com.onebigplanet.service.advisor.ExceptionAdvisor"/>
    <bean id="cachingAdvisor" class="com.onebigplanet.service.advisor.CacheAdvisor"/>   
    <bean id="businessIntelligenceAffiliateAdvisor" class="com.onebigplanet.service.advisor.BusinessIntelligenceAffiliateAdvisor"/>

    <!-- Writable datasource -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:/ObpDS"/>

    <!-- ReadOnly datasource -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="readOnlyDataSource" jndi-name="java:/ObpReadOnlyDS"/>  

    <!-- Map the transaction manager to allow easy lookup of a UserTransaction -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"/>

    <!-- Annotation driven transaction management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

**applicationContext-test.xml** This is only included when running the unit tests. It's purpose is to overwrite some of the beans declared in the other config files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>         
    <!-- Overwrite the property configurer bean such that it reads the test properties file instead -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="/obp-test.properties"/>
    </bean> 

    <!-- All DAOs should use the test datasource -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${testDataSource.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${testDataSource.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${testDataSource.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${testDataSource.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="readOnlyDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${testDataSource.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${testDataSource.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${testDataSource.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${testDataSource.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- 
        Overwrite the JTA transaction manager bean defined in applicationContent-service.xml with this one because
        the implementation of the former is provided by JBoss
    -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
<beans>
```

Comment: I thought this might get more looks with "java" and "junit" tags, so I retagged.  Wish I could help with the answer!

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I run a similar setup very similar to yours with no problems. Can you post some sample code (including your context xml files)?  Also, do you have other dependencies on cglib? Even so, can you try removing it from the classpath just to see if the beans wire?

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you're referencing an implementation class instead of an interface. There is an [excerpt here](http://books.google.com/books?id=G4jk-NOpF7gC&pg=PA192&lpg=PA192&dq=spring+cglib+jdk+proxy+interface&source=web&ots=PGqNjejNK9&sig=DhXUwccDLSH6AM4mWWb9mnQlfMs&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=9&ct=result) with more detail.

A Spring forum post: ["Mixing JDK and CGLIB proxies"](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=62668)

A great blog post explaining [pros and cons of JDK vs. CGLIB proxies](http://insufficientinformation.blogspot.com/2007/12/spring-dynamic-proxies-vs-cglib-proxies.html).

Answer (score 3):

Hey Jean, CGLib proxies are created by subclassing the class to be proxied -- you're attempting to proxy another proxy which isn't allowed since proxies are themselves final classes.  Hence:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class $Proxy25`

Comment: Without having a Spring app in front of me to test, I suspect its because you're including both the prod and test contexts when you bootstrap the container.  I would try externalizing the advice into its own file and then create a file for each of the prod and test data sources and tx-managers.

Comment: I've had a similar problem with multiple instances of the same bean ID.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the solution was already shared and I am also sure the original requester must have found a solution, since it is a one year old query. For public interest however let me mention it here. Spring was using CGLIB because of the following declaration.

```
<!-- Post-processor for @Aspect annotated beans, which converts them into AOP advice --> 
<bean class="org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator">
      <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

The property should be set to false, so that the CGLIB is not triggered instead JDK Dynamic Proxying.

```
<property name="proxyTargetClass" value="false"/>
```

Hope that helps.